# Axis is not updated when a bar is added to chart

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I have tab pane that includes a few bar charts which are updated dynamically by threads.

I am using JavaFX8. I have a function that appends data to the bar chart by adding a new bar.

The issue is: When I'm appending a new bar, no name is displayed in the x-axis.

When I am in full window mode, no names appear, but when I resize to a smaller window size, they do show up.
When I am playing around with the window size, everything works.

```java
@FXML
private BarChart FlowNumberOfRunsChart;
@FXML
private BarChart AverageFlowsRunTimeChart;

@FXML
private void initialize() {

    CategoryAxis FlowNumberOfRunsChartcategoryAxis = (CategoryAxis) FlowNumberOfRunsChart.getXAxis();
    Node label1 = FlowNumberOfRunsChartcategoryAxis.lookup(".axis-label");
    label1.setTranslateY(10);
    CategoryAxis AverageFlowsRunTimeChartcategoryAxis = (CategoryAxis) AverageFlowsRunTimeChart.getXAxis();
    Node label3 = AverageFlowsRunTimeChartcategoryAxis.lookup(".axis-label");
    label3.setTranslateY(10);
}

public void initFlowsChart(List<DTOStatisticData> flowsStatisticData) {
    Platform.runLater(() -> {
        FlowNumberOfRunsChart.getData().clear();
        AverageFlowsRunTimeChart.getData().clear();

        XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();
        flowsStatisticData.stream().forEach(flowStatisticData -> {
            series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(flowStatisticData.getName(), flowStatisticData.getTimesRun()));
        });
        FlowNumberOfRunsChart.getData().add(series1);

        XYChart.Series series2 = new XYChart.Series();
        flowsStatisticData.stream().forEach(flowStatisticData -> {
            series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data(flowStatisticData.getName(), flowStatisticData.getAverageTime()));
        });
        AverageFlowsRunTimeChart.getData().add(series2);

    });
}
```

I've tried to clear the data and add it to the chart again after I called to `initFlowsChart` but it didn't change anything.

Comment: This is (what I consider) a bug with `CategoryAxis`. Either disable the [chart's animation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/chart/Chart.html#animatedProperty()) or make sure [the categories](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/chart/CategoryAxis.html#getCategories()) of the `CategoryAxis` is kept up to date. And double check that all updates to the chart(s) are done on the _JavaFX Application Thread_.